# Azure AD 2FA API Endpoints

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is anyone aware of an API I can use to automate Re-Register for 2FA authentication for my users in Azure AD? Any help, pointing to the documentation or other would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not out yet, it is present in the Graph API User Voice: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40624027-support-re-register-for-mfa-for-a-user-with-graph

If you want this as well, go ahead and cast your vote to this.